# json_decode php5.3 bug or miss understood?

Tags: php, json

I have JSON string like:

```
'"[{\"type\": \"EDITOR\", \"value\": \"fsddfsdsfdfs\"}, {\"type\": \"CITA\", \"value\": \"Bug:\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t0 open / 0\\n\\t\\t\\t\\n \\n Feature:\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t1 open / 1\\n\\t\\t\\t\"}]"'
```

json_decode fails to decode it.

Removing " mark from start and end makes it to work

```
'[{\"type\": \"EDITOR\", \"value\": \"fsddfsdsfdfs\"}, {\"type\": \"CITA\", \"value\": \"Bug:\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t0 open / 0\\n\\t\\t\\t\\n \\n Feature:\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t1 open / 1\\n\\t\\t\\t\"}]'
```

test code

```
$test1 = '"[{"type": "EDITOR", "value": "fsddfsdsfdfs"}, {"type": "CITA", "value": "Bug: 0 open / 0 Feature: 1 open / 1 "}]"';
print_r(json_decode($test1));
echo json_last_error().'<br>';
$test2 = '[{"type": "EDITOR", "value": "fsddfsdsfdfs"}, {"type": "CITA", "value": "Bug: 0 open / 0 Feature: 1 open / 1 "}]';
print_r(json_decode($test2));
```

Am I missing something or using it wrong?

Comment: You seem to have the solution already: Remove the starting and trailing `"`

Comment: Are all these backslashes part of the string?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not call your string a "JSON string", because it is none. You surely did not get this string using json_encode(). The [grammar for JSON](http://www.json.org/) has only two top-level productions:

```
JSON is either an object {...} or an array [...] (and nothing else)
```

It follows that:

```
JSON-string is either "{...}" or "[...]" or '{...}' or '[...]' (and nothing else)
```

Comment: I didn't use json_encode() I used JSON.stringify for array in javascript. After that I send it to server.

Comment: So you likely added enclosing quotes to the string obtained by JSON.stringify(). This could have happen either in Javascript before sending or in PHP after the receipt.

Answer (score 2):

The " mark at the start and end marks its content as a string, disabling parser to detect objects ({}) and arrays ([])

Remove it as you found and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This appened to me too after moving from php5.2 to 5.3.

I have a script that send from javascript using JSON.stringify(response) and receive in PHP with json_decode, and it stopped working.

Don't know the differences from the two php versions, but i had to add stripslashes to make i work again.

$array=json_decode(stripslashes($IDS));